# PHPunit expectation on Mock object is not fulfilled

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, expectations

Here is my class:

```
public function __construct(Manager $moduleManager, Source\Yesno $yesNo)
{
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->yesNo = $yesNo;
}

public function my1()
{
    $this->moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('');
    $this->yesNo->toOptionArray();
}

public function my2()
{
    $this->moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('');
    $this->yesNo->toOptionArray();
}
```

Here is my test:

```
...
    $this->observerMock = $this->getMock(
        'path\to\Observer',
        null,
        [$this->moduleManagerMock, $this->yesNoMock],
        '',
        true
    );
...
public function testMy1()
{
    $this->moduleManagerMock->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('isOutputEnabled');
    $this->yesNoMock->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('toOptionsArray');
    $this->observerMock->my1();
    $this->observerMock->my2();
}
```

Test returns:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to 
>   when invoked 2 time(s). Method was expected to be called 2 times,
>   actually called 0 times.

My question is: I have faced with such things few times, but every time I can't understand what is going on. Why first expectation is proper, and 2nd not proper?

## Upd.1

I forgot to say that I faced with such situation few times.
Here is what I've noticed. Using xDebug I saw that inside test

```
[this]
    [moduleManager] => ModuleManager_Mock_Name_<hash #1>
    [yesNo] => YesNo_Mock_Name_<hash #2>
    [observerObject] =>
        [moduleManager] => ModuleManager_Mock_Name_<hash #1>
        [yesNo] => YesNo_Mock_Name_<hash #3> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

moduleManager objects has the same cache inside unittest object and inside observer object. If I apply smth on moduleMatcher - it appear in both places

Hash of $unittest->yesNo differ from $observerObject hash. If I set matcher for some method - it applies only inside unittest class!!!

Why did it happen? How to prevent create different objects

## Upd.2 FOUND!

When you create object through object manager

```
    $this->observerMock = $objectManager->getObject(
        'Observer',
        [
            'moduleManager' => $this->moduleManagerMock,
            'yesNo' => $this->yesNoMock,
        ]
    );
```

Variables 'moduleManager' and 'yesNo' should be the same as variables in constructor:

```
public function __construct(Manager $moduleManager, Source\Yesno $yesNo)
{
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->yesNo = $yesNo;
}
```

Here is code where phpunit check this:

```
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $parameterName = $parameter->getName();
        $argClassName = null;
        $defaultValue = null;

        if (array_key_exists($parameterName, $arguments)) {
            $constructArguments[$parameterName] = $arguments[$parameterName];
            continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you **should not mock/stub your *system under test* itself**. Since in your test case, the `$this->observerMock` object is itself a stub object (which mimicks the interface of another class, but without providing any implementation).

This means that the methods `m1` and `m2` are also *mock methods* that will not do anything when they're called. Subsequently, the mocked methods on your dependencies (`moduleManagerMock` and `yesNoMock`) will **never be called** and that's why your expectations fail.

To correctly test your desired behaviour, use your `Observer` class directly:

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->moduleManagerMock = $this->getMock(/*...*/);
    $this->yesNoMock = $this->getMock(/*...*/);

    // Do not generate a mock object of "Observer", but use the class 
    // under test itself!
    $this->observer = new Observer(
        $this->moduleManagerMock,
        $this->yesNoMock
    );
}

public function testM1() {
    $this->moduleManagerMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
                            ->method('isOutputEnabled');
    $this->yesNoMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
                    ->method('toOptionsArray');
    $this->observer->my1();
    $this->observer->my2();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I also tried your way before, and tried it once again now. Unfortunately I'm getting the same result. Some magic is happening.